# How to get ms in cast time function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a function like this

```
cast(end-start as time(0))
```

This gives me the time in `hh:mm:ss`. How do I get it in `hh:mm:ss.ms`?

Comment: Just change the scale from 0 to 2 (or whatever you need, up to 7). [See official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @ZoharPeled tried that,but it produces the same result

Comment: You need to show some sample data then, because `select cast(current_timestamp as time(3))` works. Probably you aren't storing the ms.

Comment: @DaleK I have my milliseconds values as 0 in both my start and finish column.It typically looks like '2019-08-06 18:00:04.000'

Comment: Well, if both are 0, how can there be any difference between them?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I understand that but can I have the difference in hh:mm:ss.ms with the understanding that the ms part would always only have 0s

Comment: So that's a formatting question, then... You can format the string representation of the time value anyway you like, but the actual value would still be the same... This is a display layer problem, not a database problem.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in my comment - just change the scale:

```sql
DECLARE @D1 DateTime = '2020-06-04T00:00:00', 
        @D2 DateTime = '2020-06-04T01:02:03.456';

SELECT  CAST(@D2 - @D1 As Time(0)) As [Scale 0],
        CAST(@D2 - @D1 As Time(2)) As [Scale 2],
        CAST(@D2 - @D1 As Time(7)) As [Scale 7]
```

Results:

```
Scale 0     Scale 2             Scale 7
01:02:03    01:02:03.4600000    01:02:03.4570000
```

*BTW, Note that the last column shows 457 as the milliseconds when the actual difference is 456. This is not a mistake but a limitation of the `DateTime` data type - it's not accurate enough to show actual milliseconds, so it rounds them to the nearest 0, 3, or 7.

See [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for more details about the `Time` data type.

Answer (score 0):

As you have specified time(0), you are not getting the milliseconds part. You can specify the number of milliseconds you want (0 to 7) for the time datatype and accordingly you will get the value.

[Read more on Time datatype in MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
declare @test datetime = '2019-08-06 18:00:04.000'

SELECT cast(@test as time(2)) as timevalue
```

> 18:00:04.00

I re-read your question, as you dont have difference in the milliseconds part, you will always have `.00` for them, even if you are having `time(2)` specifiying 2 digits precision for milliseconds.

```sql
declare @start datetime = '2019-08-06 18:00:04.000'
declare @end datetime = '2019-08-06 18:00:05.000'

SELECT cast(@end - @start as time(2))
```

> 00:00:01.00